# Why is the collector current I_c for a normal common emitter BJT circuit LARGER than that of the Darlington transistor circuit configuration?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, darlington

I'm a noob to electronics and have been reading up on transistors.

I tried to [simulate](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2050%205%2043%0Aw%20208%20176%20288%20176%200%0Aw%20288%20176%20288%20208%200%0Aw%20288%20240%20288%20288%200%0Ag%20288%20288%20288%20336%200%0Aw%20208%20176%20208%20192%200%0Aw%20544%20192%20544%20208%200%0Aw%20544%20240%20544%20304%200%0At%20496%20224%20544%20224%200%201%200.629628922893879%200.7000283547675703%20100%0Ag%20544%20304%20544%20336%200%0At%20208%20224%20288%20224%200%201%20-0.002841158107073749%200.6947235253122218%20100%0Aw%20144%20112%2096%20112%200%0Aw%20480%20128%20432%20128%200%0Aw%20432%20128%20432%20224%200%0At%20160%20208%20208%20208%200%201%200.6289306976419996%200.6317718557490734%20100%0At%20-224%20208%20-176%20208%200%201%200.6330390298260308%200.6522256161906899%20100%0At%20-176%20192%20-112%20192%200%20-1%200.019186586364659072%20-0.6925192022935982%20100%0Aw%20-176%20224%20-112%20224%200%0Aw%20-112%20208%20-112%20224%200%0Ag%20-112%20224%20-112%20272%200%0Aw%2096%2032%2096%20112%200%0Aw%2096%2032%20432%2032%200%0Aw%20432%2032%20432%20128%200%0Aw%2096%20208%20160%20208%200%0Aw%20-224%20112%20-176%20112%200%0Aw%2096%2032%20-176%2032%200%0Aw%20-176%2032%20-176%20112%200%0Ar%20432%20224%20496%20224%200%201000%0AR%2096%2032%2096%200%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20-224%20112%20-224%20208%200%201000%0Ar%2096%20112%2096%20208%200%201000%0Ar%20480%20128%20544%20128%200%20100%0Ar%20144%20112%20208%20112%200%20100%0Ar%20-176%20112%20-112%20112%200%20100%0A370%20-112%20112%20-112%20176%201%200%0A370%20208%20112%20208%20176%201%200%0A370%20544%20128%20544%20192%201%200%0A) Darlington (NPN) and Sziklai transistor and compare them against a single common emitter NPN configuration, shown below:

[image: Sziklai, Darlington, NPN transistors]
*All the transistors shown have the exact same gain (ß=100) and other stats, resistors etc are all the same.*

However, the collector current in the single NPN transistor is 49.3mA, which is **higher** than those of the Darlington and Sziklai configurations (42.88, 43.02mA resp.).

I would have expected a ß<sup>2</sup>+2ß gain for the Darlington and Sziklai pairs, so **why is their collector current lower**?

For the Darlington, I do understand that there is a 0.6*2 V<sub>BE</sub> voltage drop, and so the base current, I<sub>b</sub>, is lower. (Indeed it is -  -  according to the simulation). Hence, the final I<sub>C</sub> might be slightly lower.

However, this is NOT the case for the Sziklai pair. I checked the base current for both NPN and Sziklai, and they are the same at 4.3mA.

**So, why is the I<sub>C</sub> for the NPN transistor configuration higher?** Is the simulation faulty or am I missing something?

Comment: Every BE voltage is approx constant at 0.6V (-0.6V for the PNP in the Sziklai). I'm using a simulator to do the "calculations", so maybe it's the simulator's fault?

Comment: Hello Samleo, welcome to eesx! Try the following: connect a 100 uA current generator to each transistor base, and connect a 5 V voltage generator on the collectors, without any resistors. What happens then?

Comment: You talk about **common collector** yet I only see **common emmitter** circuits!

Comment: *so maybe it's the simulator's fault?* The simulator is nearly always correct, that does not mean it never lies (it does). But when you're a beginner, you're most likely misinterpreting what is happening. You want to see \$\beta\$ which is the current gain in **active mode**. Your circuits force these transistors into **saturation mode** so then you will not see that active mode's \$\beta\$.

Comment: I fix the simulation for you http://tinyurl.com/y2xoa24n

Comment: @Bimperlrekkie oops rookie mistake.. edited

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie another question: so if the transistor is in saturation mode, does I_c = *I_b still apply? Is it just that there's a different  for saturation mode or sth

Comment: In **active** mode the **transistor** sets \$I_c\$ where \$I_c = \beta * I_b\$. In **saturation** mode that is no longer valid. In sat. mode we make \$I_b\$ large, so large that \$I_c\$ becomes the maximum current which **the load** allows to flow. It is no longer the transistor which sets \$I_c\$ but the load! Then we can still say \$\beta = I_c / I_b\$ but that beta will be much smaller and it will not be a property of the transistor but a parameter we determine outside the transistor because we define both \$I_b\$ and \$I_c\$ externally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because all of those output transistors are saturated. In saturation you don’t have a linear dependency between base current and collector current. Your current is determined by the resistor and voltage drop across the saturated transistor.

With the single transistor this drop is ~0.2V. With any of your darlington configurations this drop is at least 0.7V.